# how to check text only in one column of table

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this

```
<table class="paginated">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>
            <th scope="col">Error</th>
            <th scope="col">D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Error</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Error</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Error</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascripts/tablePagination.js" /></script>
```

Actually i want to highlight that row that has **Error text** in **Error column**

I am using the following script

```
$("tbody tr td:contains('Error')").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlightedRow');
});
```

But the problem is if i have **Error text** even in first column then my row is getting highlighted like

```
<tr>
        <td>Error</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
```

How can i only check that if the **error column** of my table has **Error text** then my row gets highlighted?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:eq()` to select it:

```
$('tbody tr').has('td:eq(2):contains("Error")').addClass('highlightedRow')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an extra condition to the selector.  `:eq(2)`, for the 3rd column.

```
$("tbody tr td:eq(2):contains('Error')")
```